# Recommend a solid .Net FTP library

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

Which C# FTP client do you guys recommend? There seems to be a few available and I want to go with one that others think is good.

Comment: Why do you care which language it's written in, as long as it's a .NET library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not System.Net.FtpWebRequest?

Comment: Definitely the most straightforward approach. Keep it simple and only include dependencies when you must.

Comment: The FtpWebRequest is stateless emulation of statefull protocol. If you want to transfer more than one file it disconnects and reconnects after each transfer. Also API for anything other than download/upload is ... suboptimal. Try implementing client certificates, FTP/SSL, 'site' commands, directory creation etc.

Answer (score 2):

For a real FTP library written in C# try [edtFTPnet](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/overview.html). It is free, open source and far more powerful and versatile than FtpWebRequest.

Answer (score 2):

You may have problems using System.Net.FtpWebRequest, if you want to make a passive connection to the Server. This is caused by a bug considered by Microsoft "as designed" (even in Framework 4.0)

Briefly: if the server responds to the PASV command with a different IP (227 Entering passive mode (newip, newport)) than the current connection, FtpWebRequest ignores it and continues on the old IP.

More details here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/97409/ftpwebre

Answer (score 1):

You can try our [Rebex FTP](http://www.rebex.net/ftp-ssl.net/) which is developed and maintained [since 2004](http://www.rebex.net/ftp-ssl.net/history.aspx).